# How to reference customer field which I created in AP301000

Tags: acumatica

I have created a customer field on AP301000. The field works fine on screen. now I want this field to be populated after Vendor was selected, so I tried to customize business logic with code list this:

```
 protected void APInvoice_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
      var row = (APInvoice)e.Row;

      APInvoice.UsrVendorKey="test";
    }
```

but I got the following error:

```
'PX.Objects.AP.APInvoice' does not contain a definition for 'UsrVendorKey' in file : Code#APInvoiceEntry(56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because you're trying to set a value to the class, rather than to an instance of this class. `row` is an instance of `APInvoice`. Furthermore, your custom fields are not directly added to APInvoice, so you need to retrieve the extension first before you can update a value. Assuming you used the customization manager to add your field, the extension class would usually be named `APInvoiceExt`. Full could would look something like:

```
protected void APInvoice_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (APInvoice)e.Row;
  var ext = cache.GetExtension<APInvoiceExt>();
  ext.UsrVendorKey="test";
}
```

Comment: got it, it is in APRegisterExt. would you please help on how to retrieve acctReferenceNbr information for this selected vendor, I thought it should be in VendorMaint

Comment: What I was trying to do is instead of assign "test" to UsrVendorKey field, I want to assign Vendor's account reference # to that field.

protected void APInvoice_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (APInvoice)e.Row;
  var ext = cache.GetExtension<APInvoiceExt>();
  VendorMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<VendorMaint>();
  graph.BAccount.Current = (VendorR)vendor.Current;
  ext.UsrVendorKey=graph.BAccount.AcctReferenceNbr;
}

Comment: the same code above works yesterday, but give me error message today:'PX.Data.PXCache' does not contain a definition for 'GetExtension' and the best extension method overload 'PX.Data.PXCacheEx.GetExtension(PX.Data.IBqlTable)' has some invalid arguments in file:

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you read all of the technical documents, specifically the T300 course as it goes over the event model. There are a few issues with your code.

First, you should be using FieldDefaulting if you want the data to populate when selecting a vendor. FieldUpdating is for when you change the value of that field.

Second, you need to get your extension first before you can do anything with your UsrVendorKey field.

For Example, getting an SOOrder extension would look like this where SOOrderExt is the name of your DAC extension.

```
var currentOrder = Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
```

After you get the extension you can then use it to access your new fields

```
e.NewValue = currentOrder.UsrFieldName;
```

Comment: FieldDefaulting will not called when you update the customer; you'd still need to call call.SetDefaultExt for the event to be raised again. In this particular case it's acceptable to use FieldUpdated to update the custom field directly. One important mistake that also needs to be highlighted in the original poster's question is that they're trying to access the class directly - so even if they wanted to update a standard field the code would still not compile. "row" is an instance of APInvoice.